# how to store web push endpoint url in database

Tags: php, json, ajax, web-push

Am trying to save the endpoint url,key and token to the database but am getting few errors leaving the code down plz check

**main.js**

```
 var endpoint =  sub.endpoint ;
var key =   btoa(String.fromCharCode.apply(null, new Uint8Array(sub.getKey('p256dh')))) ;
var token =   btoa(String.fromCharCode.apply(null, new Uint8Array(sub.getKey('auth')))) ;
var axn =  "subscribe" ;


$.ajax({
type: "POST",
url: "push_endpoint_save.php",
dataType : "json",
data:{
"endpoint" : endpoint,
"key" : key,
"token" : token,
"axn" : axn
}, // Data sent to server, a set of key/value pairs (i.e. form fields and values)
contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",       // The content type used when sending data to the server.
cache: false,             // To unable request pages to be cached
processData:false,        // To send DOMDocument or non processed data file it is set to false
success: function(data){
console.log(data) ;
}
});
```

**push.php**

```
    var_dump($_POST); die;

session_start();
if (isset($_SESSION['user_id'])) {
$userid = $_SESSION['user_id'];
}
else {
$userid ="";
}
// CONNECT TO THE DATABASE
include_once("php_includes/conn.php");
$_POST = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'), true);
$endpoint = $_POST['endpoint'] ;
$key = $_POST['key'] ;
$token = $_POST['token'] ;
$axn = $_POST['axn'] ;

$user_likes = mysqli_query($conn,"INSERT INTO endpointurl (endpoint,p256dh,auth) VALUES ('$endpoint','$key','$token')");
if ($conn->query($user_likes) === TRUE) {
    echo "New record created successfully";
} else {
    echo "Error: " . $user_likes . "<br>" . $conn->error;
}
```

and this is the database structure
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mdhN7.png)

am unable to receieve the endpoint,key,token in the php file

Comment: FOUND SOLUTION!! below answer with code works,Even i think my code might work, but real problem my server isn't accepting url as a parameter to my php file so i made it work around by replacing some strings in the var

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
<?php
    var_dump($_POST); die;

 session_start();
 if (isset($_SESSION['user_id'])) {
 $userid = $_SESSION['user_id'];
 }
 else {
 $userid ="";
 }
 // CONNECT TO THE DATABASE
 include_once("php_includes/conn.php");
 $_POST = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'), true);
 $endpoint = $_POST['endpoint'] ;
 $key = $_POST['key'] ;
 $token = $_POST['token'] ;
 $axn = $_POST['axn'] ;

 $user_likes = mysqli_query($conn,"INSERT INTO endpointurl (endpoint,p256dh,auth) VALUES ('$endpoint','$key','$token')");
 if ($conn->query($user_likes) === TRUE) {
  echo "New record created successfully";
 } else {
  echo "Error: " . $user_likes . "<br>" . $conn->error;
 }
?>
```

```html
TryIt


<script  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.min.js" ></script>
<input type="submit" name ="this is an example" value= "Try clicking me Now" onclick="justTrying()">
<br>
<br>
<div id="responce"></div>
<script>
function justTrying(){
 var endpoint =  'User Your Value' ;
 var key =   'Replace it with your value' ;
 var token =   'replace this one also' ;
 var axn =  "subscribe" ;
 $.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "post.php",
  dataType : "html",
  data:{
  "endpoint" : endpoint,
  "key" : key,
  "token" : token,
  "axn" : axn
 }, // Data sent to server, a set of key/value pairs (i.e. form fields and values) 
  cache: false,             // To unable request pages to be cached 
  success: function(data){
   console.log(data) ;
   $("#responce").html(data);
  }
 });
}

</script>
```

Comment: what about the server side php file? am not getting any return value!! and no data in the database

Comment: Just replace the javascript code rest seems correct,  to verify:: add this to top of your push.php. var_dump($_POST); die; in your php script to verify whether you are getting your inputs or not.

Comment: No result still, idk whats wrong can you please check the code once again or shall i update the code with entire files, i posted the parts which are required.Nothing is logging in console

Comment: getting this error:Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 406 (Not Acceptable)
jquery.min.js:4 POST https://www.peppty.com/push_endpoint_save.php 406 (Not Acceptable)
send @ jquery.min.js:4
ajax @ jquery.min.js:4
(anonymous) @ push.js?v=0.0.0.3:41
Promise resolved (async)
(anonymous) @ push.js?v=0.0.0.3:26
Promise resolved (async)
justTrying @ push.js?v=0.0.0.3:23
onclick @ (index):368

Comment: Something wrong with your server, or you might not uploading the file correctly, sometimes it may caused by .htaccess file. i checked it on my local it works perctly

Comment: copy the code, check it in your localhost it will work

Comment: how may i generate endpoint, i do not have your all the codes, so i gave you exact prototype, change the variables and use it with your code.

Comment: hmm yeah but i need it to work on my godaddy server!!! and i dont have a .htaccess file on my server i remember having one!

Comment: var dump not logging the var we sent to php file on the console! Hope i find an answer

Comment: Thanks Bro your code works, Even my code might work i think the reason for the error is my server not accepting url as parameter, but solved it, thanks once again

Answer (score 0):

You are manually multipart/form-data encoding your request, then asking php to Json decode it.

Comment: If am not using that json decode line in my php it's returning error 406 value not acceptable!!